# Delete data from textbox on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the code from http://dropthebit.com/580/fancy-input-jquery-plugin/, and it works well so far, but I can't figure out how to delete the data from the textbox on focus.

This is some code I feel may be relevant:

```
    $('section :input').val('').fancyInput()[0].focus();

    // Everything below is only for the DEMO
    function init(str){
        var input = $('section input').val('')[0],
            s = 'Type Something ?'.split('').reverse(),
            len = s.length-1,
            e = $.Event('keypress');

        var initInterval = setInterval(function(){
                if( s.length ){
                    var c = s.pop();
                    fancyInput.writer(c, input, len-s.length).setCaret(input);
                    input.value += c;
                    //e.charCode = c.charCodeAt(0);
                    //input.trigger(e);

                }
                else clearInterval(initInterval);
        },150);
    }

    init();
```

Comment: hello, U wanted to delete the text inside a textbox when the focus even execute? Correct?

Comment: Hi, I don't really get your query, please clarify.

Comment: You have a text box or text field or textarea, once the user or client focus on that text field you wanted to clear the character present inside the field? Correct? , Assuming this might be your query I have provided the solution. Please check it out

Answer (score 2):

normally if you're using jQuery, following code should work:

```
$('#textboxID').focus(function(){
    $(this).val("");
});
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I think I'm putting it in the wrong place, where in the code should it go?

Comment: this should be added after the document is ready (cfr. http://api.jquery.com/ready/ ) if you don't want to worry about this, you could use $('body').on('focus','#textboxID',function(){$(this).val("");}); and be sure to enter the right ID of the textbox you want these actions to happen on.

Comment: <input type='text' name='nick'  style="margin-right:57px">, that is the html code for the textbox, the code from dropthebit just masks it,  so will I put this jquery command in the html or jquery code, and if it is the latter, where?

Comment: i would recommend changing the html to  <input type='text' name='nick' style="margin-right:57px" id="nick"> and then adding to the jquery code: $('body').on('focus','#nick',function(){$(this).val("");}); ( you can just append the code to the bottom of your jquery code)

Comment: Still not working, will delete the question now. It appears it's unsolvable.

Answer (score 0):

`$('textarea').focus(function(){$(this).val('')});` or something similar can work

**[FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wDR6E/1/)**

Comment: I have tried this, but I think I'm putting it in the wrong place, where in the code should it go?

Answer (score 0):

To clear the character inside a text box using Focus Event.

```
      $('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
        if($(this).val() == 'TEXT TO CLEAR') 
          $(this).val('');
    });
```

Comment: <input type='text' name='nick'  style="margin-right:57px">, that is the html code for the textbox, the code from dropthebit just masks it,  so will I put this jquery command in the html or jquery code, and if it is the latter, where?

Comment: $(function(){ // onload
       $('input:text').focus(function(){ // onfocus
        $(this).val(''); // clear value
    });
});

Comment: This the solution for your problem. Add this code in script tag. It will work

Comment: This the sample example sharing with you http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-change-default-value-on-focus/

Comment: I just edited the jquery code I posted, and I put this line:             
---$(function(){ onload $('input:text').focus(function(){ onfocus $(this).val('');clear value }); });---


just after init();

Answer (score 0):

You can clear and set again like this, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/8z27k/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').on('focus', function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
    $('#search').on('focusout', function(){
        if($(this).val() == '')
            $(this).val('Search');
    });
});
```